# Adding where clause to IEnumerable Select

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following line of code in my controller that selects the id's of the interests shown within a view (they are listed down the page).

```
IEnumerable<int> interestIds = viewModel.ExistingInterests.Select(x => x.InterestId);
```

However I want to be able to add a where clause to the select section. In ExisitingInterests there is a selected bool variable and I only want those that are true.

This will enable me to only add those ones that have been ticked to the database.

Comment: Sure - so, what have you tried, and what happened?

Comment: So....  just add it?

Comment: viewModel.ExistingInterests.Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.InterestId)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Discosultan in the comments:

```
IEnumerable<int> interestIds = viewModel.ExistingInterests.Where(x => x.selected == true).Select(x => x.InterestId);
```